Using Effort with EF Extensions WhereBulkContains throws System.Exception
I'm trying to unit test a fairly straightforward repository method that retrieves some entities which match any of a supplied list of string mapping ids.
The implementation uses EF Extension WhereBulkContains and I'm specify the entity column that the WhereBulkContain should match against using a lambda.
public List<MyEntity> GetEntitiesByMappingId(List<string> mappingIds)
    {
        if (!mappingIds?.Any() ?? true)
        {
            return new List<MyEntity>(0);
        }
        return this
            .context.MyEntity
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Include(e => e.ExtraData)
            .Include(e => e.OtherData)
            .WhereBulkContains(mappingIds, e => e.MappingId)
            .ToList();
    }


When my test triggers this method it fails with the following underlying exception.
System.Exception
Oops! The `SkipInsertForInternalFeatures` option is only available for SQL Server, and PostgreSQL.
   at Z.BulkOperations.BulkOperation.()
   at Z.BulkOperations.BulkOperation.Execute()
   at Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EntityBulkOperation`1.BulkInsert()
   at .BulkInsert[T](BulkOperation`1 this, DbContext context, List`1 list, Boolean isManager, List`1 entitiesToUpdate, Type type, String typeName)
   at .BulkInsert[T](DbContext this, BulkOperation`1 bulkOperation, IEnumerable`1 entities2, List`1 entitiesToUpdate)
   at DbContextExtensions.BulkInsert[T](DbContext this, IEnumerable`1 entities, Action`1 bulkOperationFactory)
   at Z.EntityFramework.Plus.WhereBulkContainsBuilder`1.BulkCopy(DbContext context, List`1 keyNames, IEnumerable`1 entities, Type type2)
   at Z.EntityFramework.Plus.WhereBulkContainsBuilder`1.WhereBulkContains(DbContext context, String commandText, List`1 commandTableBuilders, Boolean isNotCTE, Boolean isNotSelectOnly)
   at Z.EntityFramework.Plus.QueryHookCommandInterceptor.ApplyHook(DbCommand command, DbContext context, String hook, Boolean isNotCTE)
   at Z.EntityFramework.Plus.QueryHookCommandInterceptor.ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)

Is this a known limitation of Effort? Or have I missed some configuration that should allow this to work?
I'm using Effort.EF6 version 2.2.17, and version 8.103.0 of both Z.EntityFramework.Extensions and Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6

Oops! The SkipInsertForInternalFeatures option is only available for SQL Server, and PostgreSQL. I presume you are using neither of those two?

Why not .Where(e => mappingIds.Contains(e.MappingId))?

@IvanPetrov no, I'm using https://entityframework-effort.net/  which is an in-memory abstraction precisely for unit testing EF code.

@Marius yeah, I can switch to using a basic Where but this means I lose a lot of the performance advantages of https://entityframework-extensions.net/where-bulk-contains#what-are-contains-method-limitations.

There aren't any advantages. That library uses hacks to do things that just aren't suitable for ORMs and inevitably breaks down at some point. Look at the call stack to understand what the hack is. To make you believe you can filter by thousands of IDs (you can't) that library tries to BULK INSERT your IDs into a temporary table using SqlBulkCopy. After that it will perform an INNER JOIN with the source table on IDs to retrieve the matching rows. You'd get better performance and more maintainable code if you used your own ETL code

As for an in-memory abstraction precisely for unit testing EF code EF Core has an in-memory provider already for basic testing, and the SQLite provider can be used in in-memory mode to test more complicated queries

How many items are in mappingIds in the first place? Given that the IN(@id1,..) clause generated by .Where(x=>mappingIds.Contains(x.Id)) works with thousands of items, why are you trying to filter by over 1K individual IDs to begin with? What are you trying to do? Load data based on eg a CSV file?

The list of supported providers for Z.EntityFramework.Extensions from the NuGet package:

Support: SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQLite, and more!

and from the github repo:

Support Multiple SQL Providers:

SQL Server 2008+
SQL Azure
SQL Compact
MySQL
SQLite
PostgreSQL
Oracle


Effort.EF6 is not listed in either as supported provider.
This explains the message from the exception you get:
System.Exception
Oops! The `SkipInsertForInternalFeatures` option is only available for SQL Server, and PostgreSQL.
   at Z.BulkOperations.BulkOperation.()


That's ironic since both libraries are published by the same person (didn't say produced, a lot of old open source objects ended up)

@PanagiotisKanavos yeah, was surprised as well...
